# vim how to unmap [[

Tags: vim, vimrc

The `:map [` shows following

> `n  [[          *@m':call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "bW")<CR>
>   n  [c            <Plug>GitGutterPrevHunk
>   n  [           * :w<CR>`

`:unmap [c` works fine but `:unmap [[` fails with `E31: No such mapping`

Comment: use `unmap <buffer> [[`

Answer (score 4):

The `@` in the output means the mapping is buffer local, and you have to unmap it as buffer local:

```
:unmap <buffer> [[
```

See:

```
:help :map-local
:help map-listing
```